# plink not recognising the server details and shows error Host does not exist

Tags: powershell, ssh, plink

I have a PowerShell script that uses `plink` to connect to server using SSH:

```
$user = "{0}@{1}" -f $user, $server
$pass = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$cmd = "echo {0} | sudo -S pwd" -f $pass
$plinkcmd = " -ssh -l {0} -P 22 -v -pw {1} {2}" -f $user, $pass, $cmd
$cmdargs = @(plinkcmd, $cmd)

& plink $cmdargs
```

When this is ran I get error message saying host does not exist!

But when ran using plain command,

```
plink -ssh -l username@server -P 22 -v -pw password "pwd"
```

this runs fine and I am able to connect to the server.

Any idea why it is not reading the server correctly?

Comment: Show us [mcve]. Your script seems over-complicated for the issue you describe - What does `$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password`, `sudo`, etc have to do with the question?

Comment: Going out on a limb I suspect you need to use [splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting): `$cmdargs = '-ssh', '-l', $user, '-P', '22', '-v', '-pw', $pass, 'pwd'; & plink @cmdargs`

Comment: are you forgetting $ in front of plinkcmd ?